# Is there a JS plugin that can do this?

Tags: javascript

I recently saw a cool plugin on http://www.videobash.com/video_show/amazing-skater-11800

It's the vertical bar with all the social networks, chat, etc.

I googled a bit on this meebo plugin, and couldn't find anything useful. I

Is there a Javascript plugin that can do this?

Comment: Pretty soon it won't be "*there is an app for that*", it'll be "*there is a JQuery plugin for that*".

Comment: @Shaz, we've already reached that point. We're now at "what *can't* jQuery do?".

Comment: It's just up to your Googling abilities, now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is the meebo bar: http://www.meebo.com/websites/